# Strategy to reuse created DB_SERVICES and other instances into an EWF_APP by thread

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-20.05, eiffel-web-framework

Into my `EWF_APP[EWF_APP_EXECUTION]` the `EWF_APP_EXECUTION` inherits from `WSF_FILTERED_ROUTED_EXECUTION` defining `setup_router`.

To be able to access informations globally by thread (as far as I understand the implementation also SCOOP region in this case), I have defined a `{MY_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance` which is once (by default, thread). This `app_instance` as a `handlers: LINKED_LIST[MY_HANDLER]` which is also a once and by that mecanism I'm able to access a handler instance to get some polymorphic item_prototype I reuse into my business.

I also do the same mecanism with `db_services: LINKED_LIST[DB_SERVICE[DB_ENTITY]]` to be able to get a `DB_SERVICE` from its `DB_ENTITY` name.

With the above mecanism so far, only into the `{EWF_APP_EXECUTION}.setup_router` I create the db services, handlers, and extend the thread `app_instance`.

I figured out that the `setup_router` being called on each request, my handlers and db_services collections into `{MY_APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance` grows up infinitly causing memory leaks.

What would be the best strategy on this case? is it doable on this context as the `router` seems to be recreated on every request to setup the router with the existing handlers?

Hoping I made me clear enough...

Answer (score 1):

The EiffelWeb design is based on WSF_EXECUTION with a given WSF_REQUEST and WSF_RESPONSE.
The interface are very limited, so any kind of framework extension can be built on top of them.
The class WSF_ROUTED_EXECUTION is based on that interface and "add" the routing facility.
Check the code, and you will understand how this is implemented.
See WSF_ROUTED_EXECUTION.initialize and then WSF_ROUTED_EXECUTION.execute.
The FILTERED_ROUTED_EXECUTION is adding the notion of filters, but this is just an extension, so the "routed" design reminds the same.